# How to properly use await with pyscript?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscript, home-assistant

Here is my simplified [pyscript](https://github.com/custom-components/pyscript) -

```
async def auth(brand):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url_auth) as resp:
            ...
            return auth_token_b64

@service
def get_counters(address_id):
    auth_token_b64 = await auth(brand)

    ...
```

It worked well when I used it locally with `asyncio.run(get_counters(address_id=1))`.

But now I've uploaded the file to Home Assistant and there I get the following error -

> return auth_token_b64
>
> TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression

What is wrong here?

Comment: The syntax for async operations has changed. Please review the Pyscript website: [link](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/asyncio.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the `async` keyword before your `get_counters` function definition. This is causing the `await` expression inside `get_counters` to throw an error because it is not in an asynchronous context. To fix the issue, simply add the `async` keyword before your `get_counters` function definition:

```py
@service
async def get_counters(address_id):
    auth_token_b64 = await auth(brand)
```

Can you try this?